# Adding reference to Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy causes Ambiguous Match Excpetion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject-extensions, ninject-interception

I have Ninject configured to do DI in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. This is working fine and it injects the proper classes in to my controllers.

When I try and add Ninject.Extensions.Interception to work with my application I start getting an ambiguous match exception. This only happens when I add the Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy assembly. If I remove this assembly then it runs fine again. I also have referenced Ninject.Extensions.Intereception and Castle.Core.

Note that I have not configured interception in the application. I am just adding a reference and this error starts happening.

I am using Ninject 2.2.1.0 and Ninject.Extensions.Interception 2.2.0.0.

```
private const BindingFlags DefaultBindingFlags =
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
    BindingFlags.Instance;

public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyFromMethod( this MethodInfo method, Type implementingType )
{
    if ( !method.IsSpecialName )
    {
        return null;
    }

    return implementingType.GetProperty( method.Name.Substring( 4 ), DefaultBindingFlags );
}
```

Stack trace:

> [AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous
>   match found.]
>   System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String
>   name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder
>   binder, Type returnType, Type[] types,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
>   +9402677    System.Type.GetProperty(String name,
>   BindingFlags bindingAttr) +31
>   Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForMethodInfo.GetPropertyFromMethod(MethodInfo
>   method, Type implementingType) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.interception\src\Ninject.Extensions.Interception\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForMethodInfo.cs:35
>   Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Planning.Strategies.InterceptorRegistrationStrategy.Execute(IPlan
>   plan) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.extensions.interception\src\Ninject.Extensions.Interception\Planning\Strategies\InterceptorRegistrationStrategy.cs:83
>   Ninject.Planning.<>c_*DisplayClass3.b*_1(IPlanningStrategy
>   s) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Planner.cs:68
>   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1
>   series, Action`1 action) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:23
>   Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan(Type
>   type) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Planner.cs:68
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext
>   context) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:74
>   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve()
>   in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:157
>   Ninject.KernelBase.b__7(IContext
>   context) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in Ninject.Extensions.Interception 2.2.1.0